# Firebase Notification not receiving in App inactive state?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

How can we store firebase notifications in iOS app, if the app in kill state (inactive)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this method should work:

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app. Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote notification arrives.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {...)
```